# Why all internet bonding router requires broadband bonding service in the cloud when a user can merge his 4g internet source on his premises?

Tags: router, internet-connection, wan, cellular-internet

I have checked many internet bonding routers and all of them uses some cloud based broadband merging, I was wondering if user may has his own 4g/5g connection then he should be able to do internet merging on a device on his premises.

So then why all routers have remote broadband wan merging?

Comment: Quite obvious I think everyone do keep intentions to save money when other legit possibly exists. As far as I have learned load balancing is different than bonding.

Comment: Please edit the question instead of adding a temporary comment. The source of your "then he should be able to do internet merging on a device on his premises" assumption is still unclear.

Comment: Load balancing could already help if you use a special tool that downloads multiple chunks of a file separately. But how do you think should a single connection to a server using 2 IP addresses be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. Internet Bonding happens on the internet side, not on the Local Area Network side.

You can load balance packets between network interfaces, which is what is load balancing.

Once the packets leave your premises, it goes to the ISP and where do you catch them and combine them once it goes outside your premises through your public IP?

That's where a bonding server comes into the picture.

Courtesy: I work on network packet engineering, and I contributed to building this [bonding router](https://internetgenerator.in)

Comment: thanks for your answer, however I missed something, when I said 4G I was referring to mobile data. so attempting to bond mobile data with second broadband internet provider.

Comment: Hi @Ciastopiekarz , Again, it's the same thing. It doesn't matter whether it's mobile data or broaband. They're all Internet connections. To combine the output data of one internet connection with another internet connection, the bonding has to be done externally on the Internet through a Bonding server.